# Regex Expressions: Filter Email addresses 

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex expression

```
/^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/
```

that currently matches email addresses of the form -myemail-address@aasdf.com (do not want this email address to be accepted bc it starts with a hyphen)
If I want it to reject email addresses that start with a  - (hyphen) and only accept those that start with an underscore _  how would I modify the regex?

Another question before modifying the regex -- can emails even start with hyphens? If they can, then there's no point in modifying the regex.

Thanks.

Comment: <pedantry> "Regex" is short for "regular expression".  "Regex expression" thus means "regular expression expression". </pedantry>

Comment: I see. Ok, I ll remember that.

Comment: If you just want to *assert* that it starts with an underscore, you could use an *assertion* at the start `/^(?=_)` (which will be checked *in conjunction* to the following regex pattern).

Comment: The title needs some improvement. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out if email addresses with leading `-` hyphens are allowed, you could use a more standards-compliant regex to check:

```
print filter_var("-test@example.com", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion. A word of caution: I would encourage anybody using this to run their own tests. Specifically, try emails like `john.doe@localhost`. Although this is a valid address and validates as such, most sites would not want to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[_a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/
```

Comment: oooo I was 22 seconds too slow :-P

Comment: but then this regex won't accept emails of the form asdf-asdf@asd.com, right? I still want to keep those emails with hyphens in between, just not hyphens at start of email address.

Answer (score 2):

`-hello-world@example.net` is a valid email address.

From [RFC3696 Section 3: Restrictions on email addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696#section-3):

> local-parts may consist of any combination of alphabetic
> characters, digits, or any of the special characters
>
> ```
>   ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ?  ^ _ ` . { | } ~
> ```

It may be interesting to note also that "[periods] may not be used to start or end the local part, nor may two or more consecutive periods appear."

Answer (score 0):

Just fix the 1st part of your regex:

```
/^[_a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/
```

Comment: Not sure if he truly meant this, but "*only accept those that start with an underscore _*".

Comment: yes, only accept those emails that start with underscore_, but allow hyphens in between.